# Android Studio build apk

Tags: android, build, installation, apk

I wrote an app using Android Studio. How can I generate an APK file and install it on my Device. I tried with "make project" and "generate signed APK". Nothing works. With "generate signed APK" I was able to install the app but I cannot run it. The app does not appear in my app list. Can someone help, pls?

Comment: `Nothing works` is a rather vague error description.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Project folder, go to \app\build\outputs\apk and then copy the app-debug.apk to your device. Then, open the .apk file in your device and install it. Another method, if you have developer options enabled on your phone, enabled USB debugging and correctly installed driver on your computer, then Android Studio will automatically recognize your device and you can directly install your app from within Android Studio by hitting the Run button like you would in an emulator.

Comment: you should be in release mode if you want to deploy an apk and not to debug it, so the file will be with the name app-release.apk

Comment: Is the debug APK unsigned, as in I can share it (APK) with people directly for testing before deployment to the Play Store?

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you do not have to install the APK in order to test the app. Just Click in Android Studio -> Run -> Run '< your app name>'.

**Second**: could it be that the launcher intent to your manifest is missing?

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app is running on the emulator, what you can do is that you enable developer options of your phone and then connect your phone with the system. After that when you will click on 'RUN'the dialog box will show that your phone is connected and in that the application can be installed.